# phpspreadsheetで「500 Internal error」が発生

Tags: php

phpspreadsheetでカラム数１５で800行ぐらいのエクセルを出力していますが、
800行すべてのセルに「fromarray」を使ってスタイルを設定すると
サーバーから「500 Internal error」が返されます。
「fromarray」を大量に行うとまずいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

行数の問題だと仮定して、実験的に行数を400,200,100 と減らしていくと状況に変化はあるのでしょうか？

セットする内容は一行だけだと成功するパターンと全く同じ物を使用して比較実験を行ってみて下さい。

行数に由来する場合と、そうでない場合の切り分けが済んだらphp.ini を確認してエラーメッセージの出力先をみて、エラーログを元にデバッグして下さい。